# All code after SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader skipped

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have the following function:

```
private void populate()
    {
        String connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database;

        String selectString = "select artikelnummer, omschrijving from Artikels";

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectString);

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Open();
        int x = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            String item = String.Empty;
            item = Convert.ToString(reader["Artikelnummer"]) + "\t" + Convert.ToString(reader["Omschrijving"]);
            x++;
            listboxGeselecteerd.Items.Add(item);
        }            
    }
```

Everything that follows after `reader = command.ExecuteReader();` is skipped.

Is there anything I've done wrong?

UPDATE: Moved the `connection.Open();` to the right spot. Now, when I reach that line, my output shows `Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open`

And then skips the rest of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money is on a method higher up in the call stack eating the exception because this should've thrown one because the connection hadn't been opened.  That's your biggest problem.

The next problem you have is that your connection is not associated with the SqlCommand so even if it were opened, it wouldn't matter.

Finally, `connection.Open();` needs to be before ExecuteReader.

In addition to that, you really ought to be using `using` blocks.

```
{
    String connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database;

    String selectString = "select artikelnummer, omschrijving from Artikels";

    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    /* you also need to associate the connection with the command */
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int x = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            String item = String.Empty;
            item = Convert.ToString(reader["Artikelnummer"]) + "\t" + Convert.ToString(reader["Omschrijving"]);
            x++;
            listboxGeselecteerd.Items.Add(item);
        }            
    }
}
```

How about some simple "printf"-style debugging and posting the exception you get?

```
try
{
   connection.Open();
   ... 
}
//catch (Exception e)
catch (SqlException e)
{
    // at least one of these..
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    MessageBox.Show(e);
    Debug.WriteLine(e);

    var inner = e.InnerException;
    while (inner != null)
    {
         //display / log / view
         inner = inner.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Given the exception text from the comments (`A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`) looks more like the message you'd get just before the real message showed up, I would catch a SqlException and examine the InnerException(s).

Comment: Tried this one, it's still skipping everything after `connection.Open();`. No exceptions are called. The output does say `Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open'`

Comment: Indeed.. `A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`. How do I figure out what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Did the `Debug.Writeline(e)` Result: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)` And a whole list of where it happened. I suspect it is because I'm using this code on a 'local' database. Which is SQLCE.

Comment: It was indeed because of the SQL on an SQLCE database... Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I believe it's a configuration issue (Google will help here).  As for the code skipping, since you were able to get a message this way, it means you have an empty catch _somewhere_ that is preventing you from getting the information you need.  I would find it and replace it with some method for logging the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it's not throwing an exception, but you need to open the connection before you execute your reader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the connection before you try to use it. Move connection.Open() above your command.ExecuteReader() call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the connection before you call ExecuteReader.

Also, you don't assign your connection to the SqlCommand. You need to do it like this:

```
 using(qlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
  using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectString,connection))
  {
     connection.Open();
     reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 

     // rest of your code.
   }
}
```

Comment: SqlConnection & SqlCommand are disposable.  Some people here consider not wrapping them in using blocks a downvote-worthy mistake.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I agree. I was just pointing out his mistake. I think I was the first one that actually detected that he wasn't assigning `connection` to his `SqlCommand`. I've edited my answer to include using statements around connection and command.

Answer (score 0):

I can only surmise that you need to open your connection before you execute the reader, and that it's being skipping because an exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void populate(){
    String connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database;
    String commandString = "SELECT artikelnummer, omschrijving FROM Artikels";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
        using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn)){
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            int x = 0;
            while (dr.Read()){
                String item = String.Empty;
                item = Convert.ToString(dr["Artikelnummer"]) + "\t" + Convert.ToString(dr["Omschrijving"]);
                x++;
                listboxGeselecteerd.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, what are you doing with the 'int x'? I see you are incrementing it, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx is an interesting read for understanding the 'using' statements. If you want to understand why.

Comment: the `int x` was a remainder from something I used an array for. Must've forgotten to delete it.