# All code after MySqlDataReader.ExecuteReader getting skipped

Tags: c#, mysql

I am in the process of connecting my C# Windows Forms application with a MySql database. The issue occurs during the use of MySqlDataReader for execution of data retrieval.

In the method of concern,  I am attempting to retrieve the courseId of a University Course if a previous entry corresponding to the university name and course name exists, else it returns -1.

In my code, the code segment after MySqlDataReader.ExecuteReader always gets skipped during its execution. I came across a probable solution in the following link but it also does not solve my issue.
[All code after SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891809/all-code-after-sqldatareader-executereader-skipped)

The following code sample provides you the method under concern.

```
public int SelectCourseId(Course selectCourse)
{
    int courseId = -1;
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
    try
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName=" + selectCourse.CourseName + " AND courseUniversityName=" + selectCourse.UniversityName;
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);
            connection.Open();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                courseId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["courseId"] + "");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException)
    {
        return courseId;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dataReader != null)
        {
            dataReader.Close();
        }
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
    return courseId;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could provide me a well-explained solution to this issue and please pardon me for any mistakes since it is the first time I am creating a C# database associated application.

Comment: executescalar instead of ExecuteReader?

Comment: Does the reader actually *have rows?* Along those lines, does the `catch` ever get hit? You should also do `dataReader.Read()` inside the `if (dataReader.HasRows)`. Otherwise it **will** throw an exception.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: According to your code, any error should result in ignoring the error and returning a value.  So if your code is ignoring errors and returning a value why are you surprised by that?

Comment: yes it does and I checked whether it executes even if no rows are present by using a MessageBox before database.HasRows if condition

Comment: And as @SLaks, do not just catch and ignore exceptions. If you **absolutely have** to use a `catch` for whatever reason, you should make sure to `throw;` inside it if the exception wasn't exactly related to your code, so that the exception can still be properly handled by the code that led to the generation of it.

Comment: I checked without the try catch and an exception does occur (MySqlException) But the issue is if some row exists I am still getting -1 since it does not enter the if condition.

Comment: @ChirangaAlwis: If an exception occurs then clearly the `if` condition is never reached.  Debug your code and find out what the exception is.  If you want to correct errors, you should stop ignoring them.

Comment: Also, I recommend you switch to **parameterized** or **prepared** statements. Mandatory **SQL Injection** comment here.

Comment: Along the same lines as my previous comment, you're issue **probably** (without database ddl I cannot say for certain) stems from the fact that you don't wrap quotes around those strings. Try: `"SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName='" + selectCourse.CourseName + "' AND courseUniversityName='" + selectCourse.UniversityName + "'"`

Comment: Yes the code sample executed and it was the exact reason, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChirangaAlwis Do you mean the single-quotes worked?

Comment: Yes, plus a call to the dataReader.Read() under the if condition. Both has to be added for successful implementation.

Comment: I figured, I'll add it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from two things:

1. Your statement does not wrap the strings in quotes. Modify `String query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName=" + selectCourse.CourseName + " AND courseUniversityName=" + selectCourse.UniversityName;` to `String query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName='" + selectCourse.CourseName + "' AND courseUniversityName='" + selectCourse.UniversityName + "'";`.
2. You do not do a `dataReader.Read()` inside your `if (dataReader.HasRows)` block. This means you are trying to access data from a reader that has **not yet begun to read** anything.

As for the first statement, the proper way to fix this is **parameterized queries.** Parameterized queries are **actually quite easy**, automatically **handle data types**, and also **prevent many types of SQL injection attacks.**

To modify your query to be parameterized, only the following is required:

Take this section:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName=" + selectCourse.CourseName + " AND courseUniversityName=" + selectCourse.UniversityName;
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);
```

And change it too:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName=@CourseName AND courseUniversityName=@UniversityName";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, this.connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", selectCourse.CourseName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniversityName", selectCourse.UniversityName);
```

This again, handles data-types for you automatically, and also prevents SQL injection attacks. It's also **much more readable** and **much more maintainable** in general. (Ask anyone who has managed large, complex SQL statements. Most of them will agree with this. Some of them will not, out of spite, but those are few and far between.)